# How to use enum in init method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, enums, initialization

I have the following code which has an init method that takes an enum as an attribute, but I'm getting an error for an elected identifier.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ActivtyLevel) {
    kActivityLevelSedentary,
    kActivityLevelLight,
    kActivityLevelModerate,
    kActivityLevelHeavy,
    kActivityLevelExtreme
};

@interface DFUserProfile ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *weight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *bodyFatPercentage;

@end

@implementation DFUserProfile

- (id)initWithWeight:(NSNumber *)iWeight bodyFat:(NSNumber *)iBodyFat andActivityLevel:(NSUInteger)iActivtyLevel {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _weight = iWeight;
        _bodyFatPercentage = iBodyFat;
        ActivtyLevel = iActivtyLevel;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use NSNumber for the parameters, instead of NSUInteger/CGFloat etc. I would like to hear about the advantages, from your point of view. Also, kudos for developing a fitness app ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` declares a *type* called `ActivityLevel`, you need a *variable* or *property* with that type.

For example you might declare the property:

```
@property (nonatomic) ActivityLevel activityLevel;
```

and then declare your method as:

```
- (id)initWithWeight:(NSNumber *)iWeight
             bodyFat:(NSNumber *)iBodyFat
    andActivityLevel:(ActivityLevel)iActivtyLevel // note use of the enumeration type
{
    ...

    _activityLevel = iActivityLevel;
```

Comment: How can I sign different values to each of the enums?  Such as this:

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ActivityLevel) {
    kActivityLevelSedentary = 1.2,
    kActivityLevelLight = 1.375,
    kActivityLevelModerate,
    kActivityLevelHeavy,
    kActivityLevelExtreme
};

Comment: @ProgramGuy - `enum`'s are integral types and you can assign specific integral values to the literals if you wish. If no explicit value is given for the first literal then it has the value 0, any other literal without an explicit value is given the value of the preceding literal + 1. The default integral type used for enum's is `int`, in your example this is changed to `NSUInteger` by your use of the `NS_ENUM` macro. Your syntax for assigning values is correct, your error is that you have specified floating point constants.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a variable of the type of the enum, you can't store it directly into the enum, that is a type.  Add this:

```
@property (nonatomic) ActivityLevel activityLevel;
```

then in your init method:

```
_activtyLevel = iActivtyLevel;
```